# What are the longterm effects of pancreatitis?

Tags: medicine

As the title asks, what are the longterm effects of pancreatitis?  Having one event, is the person more susceptible to have a recurrence, or are they at higher risk of other conditions such as diabetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pancreatitis may cause a condition called ''systemic inflammatory response syndrome'', a immune system reaction affecting the whole body.

Also, more frequently, pancreatitis is linked with steatorrhea, which means oily fat, and it may cause malnutrition and weight loss, due to restriction of secretions containing digestive enzymes. Longer term inflammations of pancreas may cause fibrosis (scar tissue) in the organ, therefore restricting the endocrine functions including insulin secretion, so acquired diabetes is another risk.

Obstruction of the bile duct and jaundice, leading to possible liver damage is another complication of pancreatitis.